# interfacing wxpython and bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell, wxpython

I am here with a question that is it possible to interface wxpython(GUI) and shell(bash)(back end) script. to download file from ftp and install it on system and run licence file?

Thanks for help in advance ,and pls share sample code to that process if you guys have,,,

Comment: Possible dublicate of an already closed thread of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000189/back-end-programming

Comment: ya that is lil different from this.

Comment: You are right, the subject is a bit different. What have you tried? Do you have any code already?

Comment: I have oly GuI model for that i used wxpython ,,bt i wants to use bash script and then call that script from GUI (ex:: if user clcik a button then file should be downloaded from the ftp etc,)..can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python you can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import wx, os

script = "/path/to/script"

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'wxButton')
        self.button = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Click Me!')
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_click)

        self.Show(True)

    def on_button_click(self, event):
        os.system(script)

app  = wx.PySimpleApp()
main = myFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Replace the value of `script` with the actual path to your script.